# Print to matlab command line via com

Tags: matlab, com

I am using the following or similar code to open a matlab session via python:

```
import win32com.client
ML=win32com.client.Dispatch("Matlab.Desktop.Application")
ML.Execute("disp('a')")
```

Now i want to print something on the matlab command line. Everything I try is printed on the python command line, not on the matlab command line.

Comment: You probably have to set your handle to be visible first: `ML.Visible = 1`

Comment: @Pphoenix: When using `.Desktop` the window is visible per default.

Comment: Yes, you are correct :) When I use the `matlab.aplication` I can get it to print though. From http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/matlab_external/introduction_brd0vd4-1.html#f97358 there seems to be 3 different types: Matlab.Application, Matlab.Autoserver, Matlab.Desktop.Application which does three different things.